# Как получить список колонок таблицы и их типов?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

Как получить список колонок и типы колонок в базе SQLite? А потом динамически добавить название колонки в Label + добавить LineEdit или Spin Box в зависимости от типа колонки, если тип колонки Text - LineEdit , если тип integer - Spin Box. Qt C++

```
 QHBoxLayout* Layout = new QHBoxLayout;
 Layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMaximumSize);
 QSqlQuery* queryTow = new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);
 QString sqlQueryTow = QString("SELECT column_name,column_type FROM table_name=%1").arg(query->value(0).toString());
 queryTow->prepare(sqlQueryTow);
 queryTow->exec();

     while (queryTow->next()) {                
         QLabel *Label = new QLabel(this);                
         QString columnName = queryTow->value(0).toString();
         Label->setText(columnName);
         Layout->addWidget(Label);
         QString columnType = queryTow->value(1).toString();
         if(columnType="TEXT") {
            QLineEdit *LineEdit = new QLineEdit();
            Layout->addWidget(LineEdit);
         } else if (columnType="INTEGER") {
            QSpinBox *SpinBox = new QSpinBox(this);
            Layout->addWidget(SpinBox);
         }
     }
```

Динамически добавляя Label, LineEdit и SpinBox , как назвать их уникально ?

Comment: Вам нужно получить информацию о какой-то конкретной таблице? `.schema` не годится?

Comment: @Harry Да конкретной таблицы надо получить информацию

Comment: @Harry Не понимаю что такое .schema ?

Answer (score 0):

Получить информацию по конкретной таблице можно с помощью запроса ко внутренней таблице `sqlite_master` -

```
select * from sqlite_master where name='Имя_Таблицы';
```

Руками, работая в стандартной оболочке - команда `.schema` выведет информацию о таблицах - обо всех, если без параметров, или о конкретной при запросе

```
.schema Имя_Таблицы
```

Кстати, вот [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/223451/) статья о внутренних таблицах SQLite.

Comment: Допусти я сделал запрос QString sqlQueryTow = QString("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name=%1").arg(query->value(0).toString());
             queryTow->prepare(sqlQueryTow);  Как мне тперь вывести имена и увидеть типы колонок в таблице ?

Comment: QString Table = queryTow->value(0).toString();          
             while (queryTow->next()) {
                 qDebug()<<Table;
             } Выдаёт :QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record

Comment: "SELECT column_name,column_type FROM table_name " надо что то вроде такого запроса. Я с тем что вы написали не понимаю как работать .